# Format percentage using PHP

Tags: php

I would like to format 0.45 as 45%.

I know I can just do something like `FLOOR($x*100).'%'`, but wonder if there is a better way (better is defined as more standard and not necessarily faster).

One thought is http://php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php.  Is this a better way?  Has anyone used it and can you show an example?  Thanks

Comment: Whyt do you use `floor()`? Wouldn't it result in 50%?

Comment: Personally I just multiply by 100 and floor. It's simple logic.

Comment: No it looks like fine. I suppose it's always x % in every locale.

Comment: @Sn0opy.  If $x=.4599, then floor($x*100)=floor(45.99)=45.  As Colin said, I should use round().

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Most likely, you want `round` instead of `floor`. But otherwise, that would be the most "standard" way to do it. Alternatively you could use `sprintf` such as:

`sprintf("%.2f%%", $x * 100)` which would print the percentage of $x with two decimal points of precision, and a percentage sign afterwards.

The shortest way to do this via `NumberFormatter` is:

```
$formatter = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
print $formatter->format(.45);
```

It would be better to do this if your application supports various locales, but otherwise you're just adding another line of code for not much benefit.

Comment: Yes, round instead of floor.  Have you tried using numberformatter?

Comment: @user1032531 See revised answer

Comment: Colin, thanks! Can you explain the **"%.2f%%"** portion or point me in the right direction to understand it better? Thanks again!

Comment: @ToddBenrud %.2f is a special format specifier. The "%" denotes the beginning of the format specifier, the "f" indicates that the output should be a float, and the ".2" indicates that it should have a precision of two decimal points. Because "%" specifies the beginning of the format, two percent signs must be used if you want to actually print a percent sign. Thus the ending %%. Additional detail here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Comment: You may need to enable NumberFormatter in your php.ini by uncommenting this line: extension=ext/php_intl.dll  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554177/fatal-error-class-numberformatter-not-found) SO question for more information.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use a function.

```
function percent($number){
    return $number * 100 . '%';
}
```

and then use the following to display the result.

```
percent($lab_fee)
```