# Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

Tags: php

I've been using this exact same code for ages, and I have never had a single problem. Now all of a sudden it has stopped working.

I have read across the internet about this problem, and apparently you need `PHP 5.3 or higher` installed, and the `PHP intl` plugin installed. I have both of these, yet I am still receiving a `Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found` error whenever I use the following function:

```
function format_item($value)
{
       $format = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);
       return $format->formatCurrency($value, 'AUD');
}
```

Also, here is a snippit from my `php.ini` file showing that I have the `PHP intl` plugin installed:

```
[intl]
intl.default_locale = fr_FR
; This directive allows you to produce PHP errors when some error
; happens within intl functions. The value is the level of the error produced.
; Default is 0, which does not produce any errors.
intl.error_level = E_WARNING
```

I also have the `extension=php_intl.dll` in my `php.ini`, and it is also in my directory.

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Did you uncomment the extension from php.ini? Did you restart apache after you uncommented it? I found this, look at it and see if it helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1451468/intl-extension-installing-php-intl-dll

Comment: Yes, it is uncommented. I will take a look at that link

Comment: create `phpinfo.php` and in it put: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` then navigate to the page. Confirm your version and the extension are in-fact loaded.

Comment: Some other useful debugging tools may be to look at your phpinfo and also looking at what extensions are actually loading with get_loaded_extensions. You can use php -i on the command line or phpinfo(). http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-loaded-extensions.php

Comment: PHP is definitely working. I do not have those .dll files, so I downloaded the latest version to get the .dlls and put them in my directory. The latest version of PHP doesn't even have these .dlls, so how am I supposed to get them?

Comment: The currency code should be wrapped in quotes.. Should be `'AUD'`. Check the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.formatcurrency.php

Comment: @WadeShuler it is in my file, for some reason it didn't paste them in the post. I will edit it

Comment: Do you have: `use NumberFormatter;` at the top of your file? If not, try removing the backslashes before `NumberFormatter` in the 2 places. Works both ways for me, no errors, but worth a shot. Other than that, I am out of ideas. If there is a newer version of PHP, upgrade to it and see. Maybe a bug with that version, or something went wrong with it.

Comment: Neither of those things worked. I'm going to try upgrading wamp

Comment: So it happens that I already have the latest version of Wamp installed. What am I supposed to do now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be some really weird problem, and I somehow fixed it by doing the following:

I upgraded my PHP in Wamp through [this](http://john-dugan.com/upgrade-php-wamp/)  tutorial. I also updated my timezone in `php.ini` When I upgraded it didn't work, so I reverted back to my previous version of PHP, and voilà - it worked.

I have absolutely no idea how this solved the problem, however it worked for me.

Answer (score 78):

All you need is:

```
apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

No need to change php.ini or do anything else. (Tested on PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04).

The most up-voted answer here has you uncommenting a .dll which will never solve anything unless you are on a Windows server!

Comment: Yes I too encountered it few days ago and somewhere else saw `brew install php7.0-intl` for Mac and just tried `apt-get install php7.0-intl` and viola!

Comment: Thanks, I encountered an issue almost similar to this but since I was using php7.3 `sudo apt-get install php7.3-intl` worked for me

Answer (score 68):

You just need to enable this extension in `php.ini` by uncommenting this line:

```
extension=ext/php_intl.dll
```

For more details visit, [Enable intl extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837949/2475091)

Comment: If `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` didn't solve the problem try `extension=php_intl.dll`

Comment: Or `extension=intl`

Comment: @Marleen Thank you! (Xampp on Win11)

Comment: uncommenting `extension=php_intl.dll` works for me in php 5.6

Answer (score 29):

This worked for me (Ubuntu 18.10, PHP 7.2.15)

```
sudo apt-get install php-intl
service apache2 restart
```

Comment: I fix this for my 7.4 php server
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl

Answer (score 13):

I am using PHP 5.5 version and got the same error in Ubuntu Machine. **I have installed php5-Intl package and restarted my apache server.** This resolved the issue.

For PHP5

```
sudo apt-get install php5-intl
```

For PHP7

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-intl
```

For Mac OS X, use the following command for PHP5.6

```
brew install php56-intl
```

For different OS, checkout this page : http://php.net/manual/en/intl.installation.php

**To check successful installation, run the command php -m. This should show the intl package in the list.**

If you are using XAMPP in Mac OS X, php-intl will sometimes create different problems. You can follow the debug steps mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32404183/3534696)

If you are facing **Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/intl.so'** error, follow the steps as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38304256/3534696)

Comment: thanks. it has given me clue for solving the issue

Answer (score 10):

This means that your `intl` package for PHP is not installed and/or not enabled.

**Step 1**

Make sure that you install `php7.2-intl` (or check that it is installed). In my case, I had PHP 7.2, but the version could change.

To install, I used

```
sudo apt install php7.2-intl
```

**Step 2**

After a successful installation, go to `php.ini` and enable that extension by removing the comment, as follows

```
extension=intl
```

**Step 3**

Retstart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: i just opened php.ini in xampp server and enable extension=intl
 and its working great thanks a lot

Answer (score 9):

I am running on ubuntu-16.04 and I am using php7, I had the same issue,
It is because of the **php_intl** extension

the way I fixed it-

- First check the extension is installed or not on your server, use below command to check it

  ```
  php -m | grep intl
  ```
- If there's no results, you must need to install it
- If not installed, let's install it

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install php-intl
  ```
- Finally you need to restart your web server after you install

[Class 'NumberFormatter' not found error in simple PHP program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33876590/class-numberformatter-not-found-error-in-simple-php-program)

https://www.howtoinstall.co/en/ubuntu/xenial/php-intl

Answer (score 8):

for additional, if someone come here and on Laravel using `php artisan serve` and facing this problem, and already uncomment

```
extension=intl
```

on php.ini, don't forget to restart your Laravel dev server.

Comment: This was my issue thanks! I'm using valet-linux on a new WSL2 setup and had to `valet restart`

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Google App Engine, just add:

```
extension = "intl.so"
```

to your application's php.ini file.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/runtime

Answer (score 5):

Actually if you're using xampp and php > 7.*

edit the line `;extension=intl` to `extension=intl`, restart mysql service and you're good to go.

Answer (score 3):

*outdated*

On **Max OS X** with PHP installed with the **Homebrew**, we can:

We can check is module `intl` installed:

```
$ php -m
```

We can check module info:

```
$ brew info php72-intl
```

And **install** it with:

```
$ brew install php72-intl
```

Comment: Your last command does not work.Error: No available formula with the name "php72-intl"

Comment: This method is outdated, as brew is updated and moved php to core or whatever....

Comment: intl is bundled with php formula. No need to install anything else

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error from inside docker image php:7.4-fpm, so I added the following lines to the Dockerfile

```
RUN apt-get install -y libicu-dev # required dependency

RUN docker-php-ext install intl
```

Comment: Legend, thanks very much mate.

Comment: RUN docker-php-ext-install intl, I think there is '-' there.

Answer (score 3):

(Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, PHP Version 7.4.30)

```
sudo apt-get install php7.4-intl
sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: Thank's a lot. you save my day

Answer (score 1):

Add your PHP directory in the Path environment variable.
(C:\Program Files\wamp\bin\php\phpX.XXX.XXX for wamp)

It has worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Change in php extensions did not work for me so I updated my php version from php 5.6.25 to 7.0.10 and it worked

Answer (score 0):

**Solutions For ALL Windows and Mac.**

Most of time this extension is not there, You just need to enable this extension in php.ini by uncommenting this line,

```
          extension=intl
```

if that line doesn't exists then add that line as like below in any place below first line,

```
         extension=intl
         extension=ext/php_intl.dll
```

for better result add below as like as well because with above one is in some scenario not working with only below one,

```
         extension=php_intl.dll
```

Then it look like this,

```
         extension=ext/php_intl.dll
         extension=php_intl.dll
         extension=intl
```

**After That Mostly Don't Forgot to restart your server in my case I am using xampp otherwise the changes not working properly.**

Answer (score 0):

On CentOS 8:

```
sudo dnf install php-intl
```

Answer (score 0):

the same problem happened to me, I already configured the **php.ini** and enabled the intl extension, the error persisted and I solved it by adding PHP in the environment variables of the system PATH in Windows

Answer (score 0):

First of all, stop the XAMPP/Wamp and then kindly remove the starting semicolon ( `;` ) from your *xampp\php\php.ini* the following code.

```
;extension=intl
```

And then restart your XAMPP/Wamp.

NOTE: For Windows, you can find the file in the **C:\xampp\php\php.ini**-Folder (Windows) or in the etc-Folder (within the xampp-Folder).

Very Important Note: "*Close your Command Prompt And Restart Again*" (It's very important because if you didn't restart your command prompt then changes will not be reflected.)

Answer (score 0):

in case of using `heroku/php` you should add this to `composer.json`:

```
    "require": {
        ...
        "ext-intl": "*"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For those ones here using docker and looking for a solution, I just added this line to my Dockerfile:

```
RUN apk add --no-cache icu-dev && docker-php-ext-install intl
```

I'm getting the image from php:8.0.20RC1-fpm-alpine3.16

Hope this help somebody

Answer (score -2):

i could just do the following and it will work perfect.

```
$numbers = 123456789;

$toThousands = number_format($numbers);
```

results will be: 123,456,789, the func "number_format" is already build in function.