# Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4, numberformatter

I'm trying to use PHP's intl extension to convert amount into words. For example,

> 1450 -> One Thousand Four Hundred and Fifty

I'm using Laravel 5.4 that runs on XAMPP 3.2.2 server with PHP 5.6.24.

As mentioned in similar questions, I've already enabled the `intl` PHP extension by uncommenting the line as `extension=ext/php_intl.dll` in PHP.ini file and restarted my server after.

```
 $inWords = new \NumberFormatter('en', \NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT);
 echo $inWords->format(1450);
```

yields the error:

> FatalErrorException: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found

I'm guessing this doesn't have anything to do with Laravel but PHP. Anyone know the solution to the problem? Thanks for your time.

Comment: see under `phpinfo` it shows it ? also try to run `php -m` to see successfully loaded extensions.

Comment: Have you restarted webserver after enabling `intl`? Do you see `intl` in `phpinfo()`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Class 'NumberFormatter' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554177/fatal-error-class-numberformatter-not-found)

Comment: `php -m` shows `intl` extension in the list, but I can't find any `intl` in phpInfo. What should I look for there? I did restart the server but without success.

Comment: make suer you edited same `php.ini` file which shows in `phpinfo` page.

Comment: Restarting Apache server didn't work, but restarting my PC did. Now  `phpinfo()` shows `intl version 1.1.0` in the list and the code works as well. Thanks a lot for help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to enable the extension in your php.ini by uncommenting the line

```
;extension=php_intl.dll
```

Comment: Care to explain for other environment such as for those of us who are on ubuntu

Answer (score 5):

You need to use

```
use \NumberFormatter;
```

At controller

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me. Laravel was complaining 'Class "App\Helpers\NumberFormatter" not found.' use NumberFormatter; also works.