# NumberFormatter Not Found in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, iis, php-extension

I have a fairly basic setup to use the `NumberFormatter` inside PHP like so:

```
$percent_formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
```

For some reason, I get a Laravel error back saying the class can't be found. I looked through SO first (this was helpful: [Class 'NumberFormatter' not found in Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44095680/class-numberformatter-not-found-in-laravel-5-4)) and found multiple links on how to set it up, but where I get confused is that it is setup - when I run `php -m`, I can see `intl` listed as a loaded extension and the DLL was already on my box, so this doesn't make sense.

Any ideas? I'm running IIS on Windows 10 and everything else within Laravel works, except this. Here is the php.ini file:

```
[WebPIChanges]
error_log = "C:\WINDOWS\temp\PHP71x64_errors.log"
upload_tmp_dir=C:\WINDOWS\temp
session.save_path=C:\WINDOWS\temp
cgi.force_redirect=0
cgi.fix_pathinfo=1
fastcgi.impersonate=1
fastcgi.logging = 1
max_execution_time=300
date.timezone=America/New_York
extension_dir="C:\Program Files\PHP\v7.1\ext\"

[ExtensionList]
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_gettext.dll
extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_soap.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_intl.dll

[PHP_WINCACHE]
extension=php_wincache.dll
```

Comment: can you show your model please where you are calling the class

Comment: Try putting the global namespace prefix operator (a fancy name for "\") in front of `NumberFormatter::PERCENT` as well.

Comment: Well that was stupid obvious - and it worked great. @salathe - add your response as an answer, and I'll give you points! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$percent_formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
```

to:

```
$percent_formatter = new \NumberFormatter('en_US', \NumberFormatter::PERCENT);
```

with a backslash () added in front of NumberFormatter::PERCENT