# I'm trying to get the results of a percentage set as a a new variable but I'm getting errors

Tags: php

I have a variable that I would like to calculate the percentage of and set as a new variable.

This is how I was trying it but I'm getting an error.

```
$amount = $_POST['amount'];
$newamount = $amount*0.05;
```

But I am getting an error:

```
Fatal error: `Uncaught TypeError: Unsupported operand types: string * float in C:\xampp\htdocs\...
```

`$_POST['amount']` is a dollar amount with symbol and 2 decimals like "$12.00".

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var_dump($amount);` what does it contain? Make sure it's a straight number with no commas or dollar signs.

Comment: `$_POST` is an array of ***strings***. Try [casting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting) it like `$amount = (int)$_POST['amount'];`

Comment: @aynber its a dollar amount with symbol and 2 decimals like $12.00

Comment: You'll need to strip out the $ before doing any arithmetic with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$_POST['amount']` looks like a number but is somehow being interpreted as a string, you maybe need to cast it to be a number:

```
$newamount= (float) $amount * 0.05;
```

Actually even if $amount were "1.23", the above line would work; no need to cast it. The problem is $amount = $12.00;

In which case, I'd suggest remove the first character.  If you know it's always $ you can use ltrim to strip off any leading characters that are $

```
$amount = ltrim($_POST['amount'], '$');
```

If it could be one of several different currency symbols, e.g. you know it's always going to be one of £, $ or €, then you can use that like:

```
$amount = ltrim($_POST['amount'], '$£€');
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to make sure you always have an actual number is to strip out all of the non-numerical characters. This helps if $amount becomes $12,345.67

```
$amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", '', $_POST['amount']);
```

Comment: This is working. So how do I restrict this new $amount to only two decimals

Comment: You can add either `round($amount, 2);` or `number_format($amount, 2, '.', '')` to it.

Answer (score 1):

Cast your `$amount` to [int](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php)/[float](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

```php
if (isset($_POST['amount'])) {
    $amount = intval($_POST['amount']);

    $newamount = $amount * 0.5;
}
```

---

To parse your currency depending on locale you can use [`NumerbFormatter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php) ([requires `php_intl` extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30554177/fatal-error-class-numberformatter-not-found/42893929)):

```php
$_POST['amount'] = '$12.00';

//----

$amount = $_POST['amount'];

$fmt = new NumberFormatter('en_US', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY);

$newamount = $fmt->parseCurrency($amount, $currency) * 0.5;
```

Comment: The error is gone but I am getting the result as 0 even when I set the $amount to $50,000.00

Comment: @IMSoP My answer was posted before OP added that crucial information..

Comment: @IMSoP Updated answer with usage of `NumberFormatter`

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't know what "dollars" are. When it sees "$12.00", it doesn't know that the dollar sign is separate, and to treat the rest as a number. As far as PHP is concerned, asking for `"$12.00" * 0.05` is no different from asking for `"$$$12.00$$$" * 0.05`, or `"potato" * 0.05`.

So you have two options:

- Change the form so that the value submitted is only numbers. If it's entered by the user, write some validation code that checks it *is* just a number, like `if ( ! preg_match('/^\d+\.\d{2}$/', $_POST['amount']) ) { show_wrong_amount_error_message(); }`
- Strip the "$" off the front before processing it, using [Duncan's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68035548/157957) of `$amount = ltrim($_POST['amount'], '$');` or [aynba's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68035674/157957) of `$amount = preg_replace("/[^0-9.-]/", '', $_POST['amount']);`

Or you could combine the two: check that it has *exactly* a dollar sign, a number of dollars, and a number of cents; then discard the dollar sign and carry on:

```
if ( preg_match('/^\$(\d+\.\d{2})$/', $_POST['amount'], $matched_parts) ) { 
    $amount = (float)$matched_parts[1];
}
else {
    show_wrong_amount_error_message();
}
```

You should also consider handling money as an integer number of cents, not a floating point number of dollars, because [floating point numbers are not precise](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/157957). So you could adjust the above to give you the amount in cents instead:

```
if ( preg_match('/^\$(\d+)\.(\d{2})$/', $_POST['amount'], $matched_parts) ) { 
    $amount_cents = (int)$matched_parts[1] * 100 + (int)$matched_parts[2];
}
else {
    show_wrong_amount_error_message();
}
```