# PHP Format Decimal Data Type As Percent with % Character

Tags: php, mysql, format

I am trying to format a number column (Data type Decimal) so it displays as a percentage, example - 95%.

My MySql column is pct_list_sold and with a data type of Decimal(7,3).

So numbers in the cell are, as an example, 0.945665, 0.944905, 0.943350 and hence, displays as 0.950, 0.950 and .943

I am trying to format the numbers in PHP to 95%, 95% and 94% with the following:

```
<td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo round($row['$pct_list_sold'] * 100) . '%';?></td>
```

All the cells return a display of 0%.

I also tried the following from an example in a post here that returned an error:

```
<td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo round($row['$pct_list_sold'] * 100), . '%' ?></td>
```

Comment: try http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_sprintf.asp it is more flexible

Comment: and in round you need second parameter "precision" http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php

Comment: Nothing in the sprintf link gives a return of a % number.

Comment: Precision is optional, and has nothing to do with wanting to format a decimal data type to % in PHP.

Comment: I tried sprintf and even though it is reformatted, I get 0.00% in all cells.                 <td style="text-align: right;"><?php
    echo sprintf("%.2f%%", $row['$pct_list_sold'] * 100); ?></td>

Comment: sorry i dont fully understand your question? you have number 0.944905 and you want it display as 94%? So whats problem is  use <?php echo round($number * 100, 0) . '%'; ?>  ???

Comment: or <?php echo sprintf("%.0f%%", round(0.944905 * 100,0)); ?>

Comment: Yes, I was looking for this "%.2f%% is what I was looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14525393/format-percentage-using-php.                                               But you helped me figure it out and I thank you. Below was my final code that worked. Thanks again.                                                      echo sprintf("%.2f%%", $row['pct_list_sold'] * 100)